# gluLookat in the case of free camera

Tags: opengl

I am trying to make a free traveling camera in a 3D space. And the glulookat function looks like something below:

```
 gluLookAt(g_eye[0],g_eye[1],g_eye[2],
           g_look[0],g_look[1],g_look[2],
           0,1.0,0    
        );
```

First three coordinates are just camera location. Last three coordinates are about camera's rotation.

Seems like the Second three coordinates are about where the camera is looking at.

But I don't really understand why we need second three coordinates. How is that going to effect our view?

For example:
if the camera starts at origin, then the camera rotate to right by 30 degree, then translate by 10 in -Z direction. Then I know where is the camera positioned now. But what should I put into the second three coordinates?

1. Camera at origin
   [image]
2. turn right by some degree [image]
3. move forward 
   [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *eye*'s position (the first three coordinates), and the *view point* (the second three) defined the *line-of-sight*.  The last three coordinates, the *up* vector, is used to determine the angle of rotation around the line-of-sight.  Rotations in OpenGL require an axis to rotate around, which is the reason for the first two sets of coordinates.  Have a look [here](http://www.glprogramming.com/red/chapter03.html) for details on viewing transformations in OpenGL.

Comment: A point (hence the name).  The line-of-sight is generated by doing a vector subtraction from the view point, `v` to the eye's position `e` (i.e., v - e).  Subtracting two points yields a vector, which is what OpenGL uses as the view direction.  Hope that helps.

Answer (score 4):

> But I don't really understand why we need second three coordinates. How is that going to effect our view?

Your head is at the coordinates in the first 3 parameters.

The object you're looking at while reading this is the screen, the second 3 parameters

For the text you've read so far the up-vector, the last parameters was something close to (0, 1, 0) Now read this:

[image]

Comment: So, Can I see the second set of coordinate is the vector from my eye to the object I am looking at?

Comment: @fiftyplus: No, it _is the point_ you're looking at, i.e. the target point. For a FPS style camera the target point would be `position + direction`, i.e. in short hand pseudocode `lookAt(position, position+direction, up);`

Comment: I think i understand it now. Just a follow up question, why it has to focus on a point? what if there are bunch of objects, if I focus on one point, what happen to the rest object on screen? Thanks

Comment: @fiftyplus: Technically OpenGL has no camera and there's no such thing like a "camera focus" in OpenGL. That `gluLookAt` operates using a target point is simply because it has been designed that way. It's perfectly possible to set the view transform with only a position and a oriented direction (you still need 2 vectors, i.e. direction and up to define the orientation). Regarding what happens if you look at one object, what happens with the others: Well, OpenGL doesn't even know what an geometrical object is. It will simply draw some geometry away from the viewport's center.